# How to automatically detect the need for iScroll?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, iscroll

The [iScroll](http://iscrolljs.com/) project provides the “`overflow:scroll` for mobile [WebKit](https://webkit.org/)”, and was started

> […] because webkit for iPhone does not provide a native way to scroll content inside a fixed size (width/height) div.  So basically it was impossible to have a fixed header/footer and a scrolling central area.

We have developed a mobile-friendly Web application, using responsive design (etc.), that uses a layout that sometimes show a fixed header and footer on mobile devices, based on the [core-layout](https://github.com/mtr/core-layout/) library, which in turn uses [angular-iscroll](https://github.com/mtr/angular-iscroll).

You can try out the [core-layout demo](https://mtr.github.io/core-layout/examples/) on desktop and mobile, and try to turn the use of [iScroll](http://iscrolljs.com/) on and off.  On desktop scrolling the different areas should work both with and without iScroll (given that the window is not too high so that scrolling is not necessary); on mobile, however, whether scrolling works without iScroll depends on the kind and version of the browser.

Recent versions of the mobile Safari browser, and Android browsers, have started to support `overflow:scroll` for such fixed-size `div` elements as described above.  Therefore, some browsers still need the use of iScroll to work, while other browsers don't.  Because using iScroll introduces some problems on it own, like proper click and touch event handling, I would like to turn off iScroll in all browsers that don't need it.

I would like to add support in [angular-iscroll](https://github.com/mtr/angular-iscroll) or [core-layout](https://github.com/mtr/core-layout/) for automatically detecting if there is any need to use iScroll or not for each browser opening the page.  I know about feature detection libraries like [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/), but it seems hard to determine the need for iScroll based on feature detection.

Does anyone know how such auto-detection can be implemented?

Another possibility is to use a white/black-list and check the browser version, but in that case I wonder if anyone has a reliable rule set for properly determining the need to use iScroll based on the user-agent string?

Disclosure: I'm the author of both [angular-iscroll](https://github.com/mtr/angular-iscroll) and [core-layout](https://github.com/mtr/core-layout/).

## Update 2016-01-10:

Since no one have suggested any answers yet, I thought that I could share some ideas I've had of how to solve this:

- If it is difficult to implement a solution to the above problem through *true* feature detection, one possible way could be to utilize [platform.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js/), a platform detection library that works on nearly all JavaScript platforms.  By including the `platform.js` script, you easily get access to information about the current browser such as

  ```
  // On an iPad
  platform.name; // 'Safari'
  platform.version; // '5.1'
  platform.product; // 'iPad'
  platform.manufacturer; // 'Apple'
  platform.layout; // 'WebKit'
  platform.os; // 'iOS 5.0'
  platform.description; // 'Safari 5.1 on Apple iPad (iOS 5.0)'
  ```

  which could be used for matching against a rule set.  However, then the
  problem becomes *what those rules should be*, to avoid turning off iScroll for browsers that need iScroll to work, and to avoid turning iScroll on for browsers that don't need it.
- Another way might be to exploit that, given a scrollable `div` with higher contents that the `div`'s height, then the scroll area *should* scroll when swiped, and one could try to detect whether or not that happens.
  Consider this scenario: let's assume that you start of with iScroll turned *off*.  Now, if the user tries to scroll the contents of the `div`, but the contents don't move, then perhaps one could conclude that one must turn iScroll *on* for `div`-scrolling to work?  How would that be implemented while providing a relatively smooth user experience?  It might depend on how fast one can detect that the contents should have scrolled but didn't?

If anyone can come up with robust solutions based on one of those ideas (or a combination of them), then I'm just happy to help.

Also, I wonder why no one tries to come up with an answer; not even a comment that says this is too difficult/trivial/irrelevant/strange/outdated?

Comment: If Android 2.3 and < is in your target devices ? If yes then you are right. Else you can deal with default `overflow:scroll`

Comment: @RayonDabre: For now, we do need to target quite a long tail of dated browsers.  However, if by your comment suggest a rule for determining the need to use iScroll, I would really appreciate a suggested answer, with working code.  Furthermore, this needs to work on (at least) both iOS and Android devices, ideally Microsoft and other mobile devices too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since no one else have come up with a solution yet, I thought I could share mine, and hopefully, this answer can be edited and improved to more precisely decide for which devices iScroll must be used.

I wrote the following [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) extension that makes use of [platform.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js/) to decide if native `overflow: scroll` `div` scrolling is supported:

```
'use strict';

var platform = require('platform'),
    Modernizr = require('modernizr');

function _isChromeMobile(platform) {
    return platform.name === 'Chrome Mobile';
}

function _isAndroidBrowserWithRecentOS(platform) {
    return platform.name === 'Android Browser' &&
        versionCompare(platform.os.version, '4.0.4') >= 0;
}

module.exports = function _useNativeScroll(platform) {
    if (platform.name === 'Opera Mini') {
        return false;
    }

    if (platform.name === 'IE Mobile') {
        return versionCompare(platform.version, '11.0') >= 0
    }

    switch (platform.os.family) {
        case 'Android':
            // In Chrome we trust.
            return _isChromeMobile(platform) ||
                _isAndroidBrowserWithRecentOS(platform);
        case 'iOS':
            // Buggy handling in older iOS versions.
            return versionCompare(platform.version, '5.1') >= 0;
        default:
            // Assuming desktop or other browser.
            return true;
    }
};

Modernizr.addTest('usenativescroll',
                  require('modernizr-usenativescroll'));
```

Where `compareVersion()`, by Jon Papaioannou, is defined in [How to compare software version number using js? (only number)](//stackoverflow.com/a/6832721/126273) or this [gist with documentation](https://gist.github.com/mtr/74856662ae32df03584f).

Now, this method unfortunately does not use feature detection, but can hopefully be further improved if anyone comes up with more facts about problematic devices or browser versions.

### Update 2016-01-27

Thanks to a generous “free for Open Source” sponsorship from [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com), I've been able to test [core-layout](http://mtr.github.io/core-layout/examples/), and thereby [angular-iscroll](https://github.com/mtr/angular-iscroll/), with a plethora of devices and browsers.  Based on those tests, I've refined both `angular-iscroll`'s auto-detect rules, and the above code.

### Update 2016-01-25

Since version 3.1.0 [angular-iscroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-iscroll) has this feature builtin.  The result of the automatic detection is exposed via the boolean flags `iScrollService.state.autoDetectedUseNativeScroll` and `iScrollServiceProvider.useNativeScroll`; where the latter is available during the `config` phase of the app initialization.

Answer (score -1):

If you only need to implement a sticky header. you do need to find out system. Actually, the latest Ios system (8 or above) [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky), you can use "position:sticky" to implement a sticky head. It's very convenient and no side effect.

Other platform(android and old IOS),you do need something like 'Iscroll',you can use platform.js as you metioned or you can simply check 'useragent'. It contains everything you need.

Comment: I know about `position: sticky`.  However, we do need a fixed-position footer too (in _some_ views), and `position: sticky` does not work well if it's not on the top of the window.  Therefore, using `position: sticky` is not a solution to the problem described above.  Furthermore, _newer_ Android browsers seems not to need iScroll to perform “`div` scrolling”.  Finally, as I tried to indicate in the question, _if_ going down the user agent route, an answer must contain concrete versions and/or rules to bring something new to the table.